# User sets BackgroundImage. Store image url in cookie so it loads on next visit

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, background-image

I am working on a website:

http://tawfiq-aliyah.co.uk/epic/Site2/

I want the user to be able to set the BackgroundImage. I have implemented this with the pop-up menu in the bottom left hand corner already. But what I want is for the data about the users choice of background image to be stored so that when they come back to the site or move to another page on the site it loads the same background image.

I have looked into java cookies on the w3schools.com website 
w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

I have looked at the example but I am not sure how to get the cookie to store the backgroundImage of the  instead of storing a username.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click handlers for the thumbnails in the background image selector you do things like this:

```
onclick="main.style.backgroundImage='url(images/back3.jpg)'"
```

If you replace that with a function:

```
onclick="setBackgroundImage('images/back3.jpg')"
```

and then

```
function setBackgroundImage(url) {
    main.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';
    setCookie('BG', url, 100);    // Or however many days you want.
}
```

And then, in an `onload` handler, do something like this:

```
var bg = getCookie('BG');
if(bg)
    main.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg + ')';
```

You might want to do more sanity checking on the cookie value though, you have a list of available backgrounds kicking around so you could just check that `bg` is defined and that it is in the list.

Also, you might want to use absolute URLs for your images rather than relative ones, that makes it easier to move things around.

Comment: Thanks a lot "Mu is too short" this worked an absolute charm.Although i had to change: main.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg + ')'; to     document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundImage='url(' + url + ')';
Just a small change to be noted for future reference. The rest of the cookie data i just copied of W3 schools the GetCookie and SetCookie functions. you can check the final code on my website as posted in the OP.

Comment: Cool, I thought you had a global `main = document.getElementById("main")` somewhere so I didn't think you'd need to grab it again in the various functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with cookies in javascript, but looking at the w3c exampple you provided, wouldn'nt it be fine to use that technique and just store the url instead of the username? And then set the img:src or background-url or what ever you are using to that url from the getCookie function? (or later, whenever the dom is ready).

An alternative could be to use local storage, but it might be overkill for what you are trying to do.